# Where is the mistake in this use of the derivative rule?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I know that $$\left(\frac{1}{g}\right)’=\frac{-g’}{g^2}$$
But where is the mistake here?
$$\left(\frac{1}{g}\right)’ = (g^{-1})’=-(g^{-2})=\frac{-1}{g^2}$$ is using the power rule here wrong?

Comment: You used the power rule correctly but forgot the chain rule.

Comment: you forgot to apply chain rule

Comment: $$(g^{-1})'=-(g^{-2})g'$$

Comment: As another user stated, you forgot the chain rule. Recall if $f$ and $g$ are functions of $x$ and if $g$ is differentiable at $x$ and $f$ is differentiable at $g(x),$ then $(f \circ g)'(x)= f'(g(x))g'(x).$ In this case, you have $f(x)=1/x$ while $g$ is arbitrary. How do you apply the Chain Rule here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you've written is true ... if you're differentiating with respect to $g$.

Remember that the prime symbol is generally shorthand for $\frac{d}{dx}$ (or whatever the variable of interest happens to be), and in this case $g$ is not just a variable but is a function of $x$ and so we must apply the chain rule:

$\begin{eqnarray}\frac{d}{dx}\left( \frac{1}{g} \right) & = & \frac{d}{dg} \left( \frac{1}{g} \right) \times \frac{dg}{dx} \mbox{   per the chain rule} \\
& = & \frac{d}{dg} g^{-1} \times \frac{dg}{dx} \\
& = & -g^{-2} \times g' \\
& = & \frac{-g'}{g^2} \end{eqnarray}$

Note that the first term in the second-last line *is* what you got, but we can't stop there because we've differentiated not with respect to $g$, but to $x$.

Comment: You forgot the prime symbol in the last formula @ConMan

Comment: Nice catch, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to apply the chain rule. Since
$$
(f \circ g)'(x)=f'(g(x))g'(x) \, ,
$$
we have
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{g(x)}\right) &= \frac{d}{dx}\left(g(x)^{-1}\right) \\[4pt]
&= -g(x)^{-2} \cdot \color{red}{g'(x)} \\[4pt]
&= -\frac{g'(x)}{g(x)^2} \, .
\end{align}

---

Alternatively, we could let $y=1/g(x)$ and multiply both sides by $g(x)$:
\begin{align}
yg(x) &= 1 \\[4pt]
\frac{d}{dx}(yg(x)) &= \frac{d}{dx}(1) \\[4pt]
y'g(x)+yg'(x) &= 0 \\[4pt]
y' &= -\frac{yg'(x)}{g(x)}=-\frac{\frac{1}{g(x)}g'(x)}{g(x)}=-\frac{g'(x)}{g(x)^2} \, .
\end{align}